# Derivative equals 1

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Consider the following curve:

$$
x^{2}+y^{2}=2 x y+16
$$

By differentiating both sides with respect to $x$

$$
\frac{d y}{d x}(2 y-2 x)=2 y-2 x
$$

$$
\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{2 y-2 x}{2 y-2 x}=1
$$

> Are there any reasons that explain why the derivative at each point is equal to 1?

Update:  I think the reason is related to the fact that the curve resembles parallel lines? But how does this explain it?

Comment: The slope of the parallel lines is 1 and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the slope of your relation.

Comment: The curve doesn’t just _resemble_ a pair of parallel lines. It _is_ a pair of parallel lines.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^2+y^2=2xy+16 \Rightarrow$$
$$(x-y)^2=16\Rightarrow$$
$$(x-y)=4$$ or $$x-y=-4$$ which are both lines with slope 1

Comment: Do you mean =2 and =-2? Root of 4 isn’t 4.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the equation is that of a degenerate conic, and factors as

$$(x-y-4)(x-y+4)=0.$$

Of course, for both lines, $y'=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x^2+y^2=2xy+16\implies\\
x^2-2xy+y^2=16\implies\\
(x-y)^2=16\implies\\
|x-y|=4\implies\\
x>y,\ y=x-4\\
x<y,\ y=x+4.
$$

So, the original implicit function $x^2+y^2=2xy+16$ is equivalent to the two functions $y=x-4$ and $y=x+4$ for different values of $x$ and $y$. Graphically, those are nothing more than two lines of slope $1$. That's why it's only natural to expect the derivative to be $1$.